# HTML Tail Tag to complement Head Tag

Tags: javascript, html

So typically, in our HTML files, the general structure looks a bit like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <!-- Meta Stuff -->
        <!-- Title -->
        <!-- CSS Files -->
        <!-- JavaScript Files -->
        <!-- Other Header Stuff -->
    </head>
    <header>
        <!-- Navbar & Header Stuff -->
    </header>
    <body>
        <!-- Body Stuff -->
    </body>
    <footer>
        <!-- Copyright & Footer Stuff -->
    </footer>
</html>
```

However, I often find myself using JavaScript Files that need to be loaded *after* the `body`, or whatever element it interacts with. As such, the body may end up looking like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- Body Stuff -->
    <script src="..."></script>
    <script src="..."></script>
    <script src="..."></script>
    ...
    <script src="..."></script>
</body>
```

Sure, I could merge all of that stuff into one large Script File, either manually or using some sort of compiler. I could even wrap all of my scripts into a separate `div` so that I can mark that as "separate" in my mind.

However, all I'm really doing is injecting a bunch of scripts at the end of my document. This stuff shouldn't really go in a `body` tag, because it's not actual content, just code.

To rectify this, I often use a `tail` tag, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <header></header>
    <body>
        <!-- Body Stuff -->
    </body>
    <footer></footer>

    <tail>
        <script src="..."></script>
        <script src="..."></script>
        <script src="..."></script>
        ...
        <script src="..."></script>

        <script>(function() { console.log('Custom code'); })();</script>
    </tail>
</html>
```

Browsers seem to be fine with this, and I'm happy with this solution. However, the `tail` tag isn't a part of the HTML specifications, and I've seen little to no usage of a `tail` tag, except old HTML4 stuff that used a `tail` tag as a `footer` tag.

So what I'm wondering is: **Is this good practice? Are there any downsides to this approach?**

Comment: Writing invalid HTML doesn't really sound like a good solution to something that isn't an issue, just stick the script tags directly in the body

Comment: Also the `<footer>` element should be within the `<body>` element.

Comment: I never put `<header>` or `<footer`> tags within the `<body>` element. I never knew that I was supposed to. I've also never had any problems with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see where you're going with this.  I've considered the same concept.  There are valid cases for putting `<script>` tags at the bottom of a document, and they don't really need to be in the `<body>` tag -- except that there is no other **valid** place to put them (save the `<head>`).  In lieu of creating invalid tags for organizational purposes, I have done the following:

```
    <section id="tail">
        ... 
    </section>
</body>
```

With some CSS like

```
section#tail { display: none; }
```

to ensure there are no errant display effects.

Comment: This is also what I've started doing. This really needs to become a feature.

Comment: Also, I recommend using div instead of section for this, as browsers like to see an h1-h6 tag as the first element within a section.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this good practice?

No.

> Are there any downsides to this approach?

You would have to perform exhaustive browser testing to see whether this worked, including text browsers and screen readers. Also, people may laugh at you, and Steve Faulkner will create an amusing meme about you... which is a downside if that may offend you.

Put all of your content in the `body` tag, and just place all of the scripts before the `</body>` tag, not wrapped in anything. They are not displayed, so there is no need to group them in an element.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <header></header>
        <!-- Body Stuff -->
        <footer></footer>

        <script src="..."></script>
        <script src="..."></script>
        <script src="..."></script>
        ...
        <script src="..."></script>

        <script>(function() { console.log('Custom code'); })();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When using IDEs / Text Editors, having everything in a collapsible group is helpful.

Comment: @Boom inventing an HTML element for this is not the answer though. It could easily be achieved without inventing anything new... using a script module loader, combining scripts into a single file, sticking them in a `<div>` tag just before the `</body>` tag... just not by using a `<tail>` element after the body tag.

Comment: I definitely agree with you. I've since changed my tail tag to a div#tail tag. With certain JS frameworks, I can still call it tail, and the framework will change it to div#tail for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not good practice. As an alternative to including scripts within the `<body></body>` tags, you could leave them in the `<head></head>` section and the code you want after the page has loaded could be called using the following Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
});
```

Or the following javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
};
```

Answer (score 0):

*HTML Tail defines the HTML code to insert at the bottom of each HTML document, usually to include a link back to your home page or insert a small graphic. It is inserted as a table data element and is right aligned with the page.*

Sorry, but I don't agree with your method.

Basic structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<!-- Some meta data -->

<!-- Title -->
<title></title>
<!-- Link to css script -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Some Content -->

<!-- Script tag to .js source script -->
<script src="example.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And simple explanation of a proper basic-page load:

When browser goes through that HTML script,

- it first recognizes the type of a script defined,
- then it runs onto a LINK tag, which directs it to the .css script. Browser reads it and first displays a style on a page,
- then it goes through a BODY tag and displays a content,
- and let's say at last, it runs onto a SCRIPT tag, which directs the browser to a .js script, reads it, and as last loads the interactivity to a page.

Which gives a user nicer experience when visiting some page.